# Kneser Inequality in multivariables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, polynomials

Based on the Kneser Inequality ("Polynomials and Polynomial Inequalities", p. 260) one has

$\Vert q \Vert_{[-1, 1]} \Vert r \Vert_{[-1, 1]} \leq C(n, m) \Vert q r \Vert_{[-1, 1]}$

where all norms are uniform norm and $q$ and $r$ are polynomials of order $m$ and $n-m$ of one complex variable with general complex coefficients.

I am interested in only real polynomials and my question is that, does exist an easy extension of this inequality to multivariable case of $d$ variables in the space $\mathbb{R}^d$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Actually I believe that this question is solved now. I found an idea in a paper of Andras Kroo and extend it to multivariate case. You can see details in this preprint http://arxiv.org/abs/1506.01859